# How Do I Reference a Global Expression in TeamCity's Kotlin DSL?

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, dsl

I'm trying to use a list of strings (options) called `myList` from one global place in my `settings.kts` (below) because I'm trying to make it more maintainable, but I keep getting this error `Expression is inaccessible from a nested class 'MySubProject'`. I've been reading about Kotlin and how to use it but I haven't been able to figure this out. Perhaps someone with some Kotlin or TeamCity DSL experience can help me?

```
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2019_2.project
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2019_2.Project

var myList = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2")

project {

        params {
            select("system.MyOption",
                    myList[0],
                    label = "My Option",
                    description = "It's an option.",
                    options = myList)
    }

    subProject(MySubProject)
}

object MySubProject : Project ({
    params {
        select("system.MySubOption",
                myList[0],
                label = "My Sub Option",
                description = "It's another option.",
                options = myList)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is making an object declaration like this:

```
object MyGlobalConfig {
    var myList = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2")
}
```

Then referencing the value in other parts of the script like this:

```
project {

        params {
            select("system.MyOption",
                    MyGlobalConfig.myList[0],
                    label = "My Option",
                    description = "It's an option.",
                    options = MyGlobalConfig.myList)
    }

    subProject(MySubProject)
}

object MySubProject : Project ({
    params {
        select("system.MySubOption",
                MyGlobalConfig.myList[0],
                label = "My Sub Option",
                description = "It's another option.",
                options = MyGlobalConfig.myList)
    }
})
```

It works and it was the best I could come up with.